# .Net/C# distributed lock manager needed

Tags: c#, .net, locking

I'm looking for a lock manager implementation that I can use to protect various resources in my distributed application. Looking for standard read/write/read upgrade capabilities.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any more details? What kind of resources? What's the plan here?

Comment: I have a shared object cache, and I need to be able to "check out for edit" an object, manipulate it, and write it back to the cache. So basically a distributed per object reader/writer lock.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a *[ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)*. It can have many locks for efficient concurrent interactions, and its methods strongly encourage concurrent thinking, such as `AddOrUpdate` and `GetOrAdd`, both of which have overloads with functions and objects.